# Determining if a factor group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G = \Bbb Z_{4} \times \Bbb Z_{4} $, and $H = \{(0,0), (2,0), (0,2), (2,2)\}$. Is $G/H$ isomorphic to $ \Bbb Z_{4} $ or $\Bbb Z_{2} \times \Bbb Z_{2} $?

I know $G/H$ has order $4$. Also, every element in $G/H$ has order $2$. I do not have full access to my usual stock of theorem atm.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does $\Bbb Z_4$ have elements of order $4$? Does $\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$ have elements of order $4$? Does $G/H$ have elements of order $4$? It seems you are capable of answering these three questions, and together they *should* tell you all you need.

Comment: Helpful. Managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf Z/4\mathbf Z$, being cyclic, has an element of order $4$, while the Klein group $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z\times\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z $ has not.

Answer (score 0):

Element $1 \in\Bbb Z_{4}$ has order 4, no element of $\Bbb Z_{2} \times \Bbb Z_{2}$ has order 4, and elements of $G/H$ are $(0,0)+H$, $(1,0) + H$, $(0,1) + H$ and $(1,1) + H$.

$|(0,0)+H|=1$, $|(1,0) + H|=2$, $|(0,1) + H=2$ and $|(1,1) + H|=2$.

So, $G/H$ isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_{2} \times \Bbb Z_{2}$.